# How to copy html response in clipboard automatically

Tags: html, clipboard

I want to copy html response in clipboard automatically without clicking on button. I have tried but not succeeded like using javascript

```
var textarea = $("#Data");
textarea.select();
var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
```

But it returns false..

How to proceed?

I have read previous posts but it not helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: @root I have read this post but not helpful.... i get var successful = document.execCommand('copy'); as false

Comment: Can u clarify in what situation would u want the copying to happen?